# Accessing items inside a variable

Tags: php

I have the following schema of the database,

```
CREATE TABLE `tz_todo` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `position` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `text` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `dt_added` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `position` (`position`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If I am writing the following PHP statement,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tz_todo` ORDER BY `position` ASC");
```

How I access the text items inside $query?

Please guide. Thanks

UPDATE:
I have tried this,

```
echo $query['id'];
echo $query['position'];
echo $query['text'];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Even the most basic tutorial would tell you this.

Comment: There are way too many tutorials online about how to do this. For start, I'd stop using the deprecated mysql_* functions and switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: For that you'll want to look in to PHP's `while` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php function and mysql_fetch_array, although you shouldn't use mysql_* functions anymore and should instead look at MySQLi or PDO, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Attempting to print $query won't allow access to the information. One of the mysql result functions must be used: mysql_fetch_assoc(), mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.

This is an example of how you would access your results using mysql_fetch_assoc():

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['position'];
        echo $row['text'];
        echo $row['dt_added'];
    }
```

It is good practice to first check if there are any results returned, below is an example of how you could do that:

```
if (!$query) {
   //do stuff when there is no data returned
}
```

NOTE: mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered, in reasonably simple terms, in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).  (Do note that you are recommended to move away from the `mysql_query` family of commands.)

The basic approach is to iterate over the results in the following manner.

```
$query = mysql_query( ...
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  do something
}
```